# Can I access the "Ti" singleton from a remotely hosted app?

Tags: tidesdk

I have a TideSDK app with a main url that is hosted on a server. E.g. http://example.com/myApp.

I am trying to access the Titanium singleton from that code, but it's not defined. Does TideSDK not pass a reference to it to the window object or something?

I haven't found anything in the docs regarding this as I suppose most apps bundle the code within.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Ti object is not available to any remote server url. This is because of the security policy in place for TideSDK.

The policy in place is to prevent any remote URL to access your entire computer through Ti object. So if you load any url in TideSDK it would not allow them to access your local computer.. and only urls from your own computer will get access to it.

Comment: Thanks! that makes sense. BTW, the documentation does not talk about "Ti", it talks about Titanium http://tidesdk.multipart.net/docs/user/generated/#!/api/Titanium